# ForeignKey String ToLower Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a problem with the ForeignKey, as you will see in the database table i have the following value "LA URBINA" in the column "EQU". in my model the property is:

```
[ForeignKey("Equipo")]
public string EQU { get; set; }

private Equipo equipo;
public virtual Equipo Equipo
{
    get { return equipo; }
    set { equipo = value; }
}
```

the problem is that in the table "Equipo" the key code is "La Urbina" not "LA URBINA" and therefore does not make the relationship, any idea to make the comparison regardless if the value is lower or upper? please excuse my bad English, I hope you understand me and you can help me

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: yes, I thought that but I can not touch the database of my client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case this can help someone my solution was

in the model:

```
private string equ;
[ForeignKey("Equipo")]
public string EQU
{
    get { return equ.Capitalize(); }
    set { equ = value; }
}

private Equipo equipo;
public virtual Equipo Equipo
{
    get { return equipo; }
    set { equipo = value; }
}

public static string Capitalize(this string str)
{
    if (str != null || str == "")
    {
        str = str.ToLower();
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b[a-z]", delegate(Match m)
        {
            return m.Value.ToUpper();
        });
    }
    return str;
}
```

in the class Equipo:

```
private string codigo;
[Key]
[StringLength(20)]
public string Codigo
{
    get { return codigo.Capitalize(); }
    set { codigo = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check what "Collation" your database is using.

For example, "Latin1_General_100_CS_AI" - the CS indicates that strings in your database is "case-sensitive" and string like "LA URBINA" and "La Urbina" are different.

If it is ""Latin1_General_100_CI_AI" - the CI indicates that string in your database are "case-insensitive" and there is no differences between those two strings.

In order to change your database collation, re-create it (nasty scenario) or right click -> options -> collation.

Comment: yes, I thought that but I can not touch the database of my client. I'm looking for something overwriting OnModelCreating or maybe with linq

Comment: If you're trying to filter data after it is loaded in your current context, you can use Linq to Objects.

You must pay attention to Linq to Entities and Linq to Objects.

If you want to be case-sensitive, query your entities in the context and use .ToList() in order to load data. After ToList() you may filter your data with Where(x => x.EQU == "something").